# Will iOS custom B2B app update automatically when downloaded using redemption code?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program, apple-business-manager

We have rolled out an iOS custom B2B app and have distributed it using redemption code sent as invitation link to the customer's email. The customer redeems the code and app is installed.

We are planning to provide an update to the same app, we wanted to know:

1. Will the app that has been downloaded using redemption code get auto updated when a new update is published?
2. If the person has been sent a redemption code before the app update, will the same redemption code point to the new updated app or do we need to generate new set of redemption code?

Answer (score 1):

We have approx. 500 users with a B2B app. Updates can be seen in the Purchases section of the app store, and it seems updates "usually" install automatically within a couple days.

But, anecdotally, it seems 10% still don't have the update after 2 months (because of device policy, no storage, not sure).

Yes, the redemption code should still be valid, but IIRC it says "this code has already been redeemed" if it has.

To force a device to update, we usually send out a new redemption code link or navigate to the purchases section of the app store.

Also note:
Unless things have changed recently, they'll need to have the **iTunes** app installed and not offloaded. Hopefully Apple migrates these links into the App Store redemption system some day.